# How do I restart a total if a cell equals 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am trying to automatically reset my total if a cell equals 0.

```
A1 9
B1 9
C1 0  <-- Reset total
D1 9
E1 9
F1 9
G1 9
H1 36 (Should = 36, resetting at any cell showing 0 and not show 54)
```

Fields `A1:G1` hold the daily hours worked on the roster, while `H1` contains the total hours worked that week. (However, I want to reset this total if there is a 0 hour rest day)

Is there a formula that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use a "helper" row.  In **A2** enter: `=A1` in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1=0,0,B1+A2)
```

and copy across.  Finally in **H1** enter:  `=G2`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wih BVA / Macros

```
Public Function sumreset(dataRange As Range)
    totalSum = 0
    totalLength = -1
    indicator = "none"
    totalLengthRows = dataRange.Rows.Count
    totalLengthCols = dataRange.Columns.Count
    If (totalLengthRows = 1) And (totalLengthCols > 1) Then
        totalLength = totalLengthCols
        indicator = "cols"
    ElseIf (totalLengthRows > 1) And (totalLengthCols = 1) Then
        totalLength = totalLengthRows
        indicator = "rows"
    End If
    For i = totalLength To 1 Step -1
        Select Case indicator
            Case "rows"
                nextData = dataRange(i, 1)
            Case "cols"
                nextData = dataRange(1, i)
        End Select
        If nextData <> 0 Then
            totalSum = totalSum + nextData
        Else
            i = 1
        End If
    Next i
    sumreset = totalSum
End Function
```

Open VBA / Macros with ALT+F11, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a module and paste this code on the right side.

On cell H1 put `=sumreset($A$1:$G$1)` and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple macro which will do exactly what you want. This works with horizontal or vertical ranges

```
Function SumAfterZero(rng As Range) As Double

Dim r As Range
Dim output As Double

For Each r In rng
    If r = 0 Then
        output = 0
    Else
        output = output + r
    End If
Next r

SumAfterZero = output

End Function
```

As with above, simply put `=SumAfterZero(A1:G1)` in cell H1.