# Excel how to restart the number count if A1:Z1 if A<B, B<C, C<D, count only if greater. Reset if not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a major issue and I did my research, still can't get the proper formula. Please check out the answer to a similar question here :

[How do I restart a number count if Cell value = 0](https://superuser.com/questions/1014456/how-do-i-restart-a-number-count-if-cell-value-0?newreg=23851808d5a34df9884507fbf780fa56)

Now what I like to do is the same, EXCEPT with a slight difference. From rows A1 to Z1 I have values. I want the formula to COUNT how many times a number is more than the previous number in the range BUT if the number is less, I want the count to reset back to 0.

So

```
A 1
B 2
C 0 
D 1 
E 2
```

The answer here would be 2.. Because at C the count resets back to 0.

Any help? I got the formula from the previous link

```
Function SumAfterZero(rng As Range) As Double

Dim r As Range
Dim output As Double

For Each r In rng
    If r = 0 Then
        output = 0
    Else
        output = output + r
    End If
Next r

SumAfterZero = output

End Function
```

So as far as I tested it, it works but I have to change it to compare logical operation "<" and then incremnt count and NOT +r so I dont know how to do that :)

Comment: Based on your definition, I get an answer of 3 rather than 2 for the values shown.  If those are intermediate counts rather than source data, the results would seem to be 4.  The rules and objective aren't clear.  Also if the range is A1:Z1, you're talking about columns, not rows, and your last paragraph isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a series of integers in the range `A1:Z1`:

```
/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
|   | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 2 | 6 | 6 | 9 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 9 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 6 |
\-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

We can place a value of `0` in `A1` and use the following formula in `B2` (and then copy it to the right all the way to `Z2`:

`=IF(B1>A1,A2+1,0)`

Which gives us a result like:

```
/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
|   | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 2 | 6 | 6 | 9 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 9 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 6 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 
\-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

The values in Row 2 represent the number of consecutive values in row 1 (from left to right) which have been larger than the preceding value (to the left).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the easy fix but I can't have an extra row doing the work, it all has to be done within one cell. I did use the VBA code example SumAfterZero which worked beautifully :) But I will try to play with ur idea I think its pretty smart

Comment: No problem, but out of curiosity why does this have to be done in a single cell? If you have sufficient control/authority to add the single cell containing the solution, why not an entire row (which you can hide if you wish) and then derive your final result accordingly from that hidden row?

Comment: Ok so. I have 3000 rows of data. Each row stretches from I to Z so thats like 18 enteries or so on. From A to H I have calculations which are based on the DATA in collumns I to Z.. So as u see, I can't simply put a new row under each row, or make 3000 seperate rows to count this data. I need it all to fit into for example.. For row 2, data I to Z, the resulting trend has to be viewed in H2 alone.. for data in row 3, data from i to z has to be viewed in H3 alone.. And so on. I hope this helps  :D

Comment: I understand - in that case, why not use the 16 columns to the right of each row (i.e. `AA` to `AP`) to hold the formula I have place in row 2 of my answer? Then you could calculate for as many rows as you like without having to insert extra rows and breaking your data presentation?

Comment: I actually did that before you mentioned it, it is a wise idea indeed but I got side tracked by java jsoup coding, I will test that out right meow :D